# React JS app: How do I load new TTS voices?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I’m building an app with the React JS library, using Electron and Node JS to package it as a Windows .exe

I used the “speak-tts” module to integrate speech synthesis. Everything seems to be pretty straightforward, but I can’t figure out how to load additional voices. I can only get the default voice.

Has anyone else come across this issue? Your advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the creator of the speak-tts module. As you can see in the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/speak-tts) there is a `setVoice()` method that you can call on your instance to change the voice on the fly.
You can get the list of available voices in the browser from the `onvoiceschanged` listener. Also there might be specific issues with Electron and this package that I'm not aware of.
If so do not hesitate to create a github issue (https://github.com/tom-s/speak-tts/issues).

Answer (score -1):

**Easiest way to do is use plain JS methods**

For reference.

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/cancel
```

***It has all the required methods. cancel(), start(), pause() etc***